# Rendering rails layouts/templates/partials outside the controller and with a custom binding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, haml, render

I have a directory containing a layout file, a template file, and two partial files

```
- layout.haml
- template.haml
- partial1.haml
- partial2.haml
```

I want to render the template, which in turn renders the partials, against the given layout using `yield/content_for` as in a typical rails view setup. However, I want to pass in a binding as well as in

`html = Haml::Engine.new('template.haml').render(my_binding)`

I'm pretty lost as to how to accomplish this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: No need to use `Haml::Engine` to compile haml. Rails will do it by default.

Comment: Partials should be prefixed with `_` in rails. Then you can use the `render` command right away.